# Express routes parameter conditions

Tags: node.js, express, routes, url-routing

I have a route on my Express app that looks like this:

```
app.get('/:id', function (request, response) {
  …
});
```

The ID will always be a number. However, at the moment this route is matching other things, such as `/login`.

I think I want two things from this:

1. to only use this route if the ID is a number, and
2. only if there isn't a route for that specific paramater already defined (such as the clash with `/login`).

Can this be done?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Expanding on Marius's answer, you can provide the regex AND the parameter name:

```
app.get('/:id(\\d+)/', function (req, res){
  // req.params.id is now defined here for you
});
```

Comment: Great, but now if I have a route for say `/1` elsewhere, it's still going to call that. Anyway to prevent this?

Comment: As long as the explicit `/1` route is added first it will take precedence.

Comment: You can place the explicit routes first, as JohnnyHK says. You may also be able to define the RegEx to not match the routes you want to skip.

Comment: Order your route handlers in priority order and then use `function(req, res, next)`, calling next() from within any route when your logic knows that it needs to pass control onto the next route handler in line.

Comment: if you use an alpha-numeric id like Mongo ObjectID you will need to change the regex

Comment: Great! Works for me. Express version `~4.15.3`. I could make two routes with this technique: `/users/online` and `/users/21`, `/users/online` and `/users/:id(\\d+)` respectively.

Comment: is the id parameter optional in this route? If not, how would I make it optional? I know that '/:id?' makes the id parameter optional but do I still need the question mark and, if so, where would it go?

Answer (score 12):

Yes, check out http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html and https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp (which express uses). An untested version that may work is:

```
app.get(/^(\d+)$/, function (request, response) {
  var id = request.params[0];
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
// /12345
app.get(/\/([^\/]+)\/?/, function(req, res){
  var id = req.params[0];
  // do something
});
```

or this:

```
// /post/12345
app.get(/\/post\/([^\/]+)\/?/, function(req, res){
  var id = req.params[0];
  // do something
});
```