# Express 4 parameter condition

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I would like to have the following routes:

```
// Services without csrf()
router.get('/user/:uid', userRes.findUser, userRes.GETUser);
router.post('/user/:uid', userRes.findUser, userRes.POSTUser);

// Rest of routes, with csrf()
router.use(csrf());

router.post('/user/subscribe', indexRes.POSTSubscribe);
```

But what happens here is that `POST /user/subscribe` is matching second route.

I've been reading [Express routes parameter conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258442/express-routes-parameter-conditions) but it shows how to filter numbers. I would like to filter 'subscribe' path:

Is there any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `router.param`:

```
var staticUserPaths = ['subscribe'];
router.param('uid', function (req, res, next, id) {
  if (~staticUserPaths.indexOf(id)) {
    next('route');
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you move your `/user/subscribe` route *before* the `/user/:uid` route, it will get executed instead of the `/user/:uid` route for requests to `/user/subscribe`. Routes/middleware in Express are executed in the order they are attached.

Comment: But what about csrf then? I'm placing in this order to disallow csrf checks to `/user/:uid`

Comment: One solution for that might be something like: `router.post('/user/subscribe', csrf(), indexRes.POSTSubscribe);` Or just evaluate `csrf()` once and re-use that returned middleware in multiple places.

Comment: Hmmm... I think it can be a little error prone (one could forget to put csrf middleware in the required routes)

Comment: You can leave your `router.use(csrf);` where it is, which should still work for any other routes placed after the `/user/:uid` route.

Comment: So maybe I'm not understanding your solution. The problem is that I need csrf to work with `subscribe` but not with `/user/:uid`. So If I place `/user/subscribe` before `/user/:uid` and leave `router.use(csrf)` after `/user/:uid`, I need to put csrf to `/user/subscribe`(which I think I can do some mistake in future as more `/user/xxx` should come)