# Regular Expression for Route Params in Express.js

Tags: node.js, express

As per various docs and blogs, as well as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258442/express-routes-parameter-conditions) and others, I'm aware that one can validate route parameters by using regular expressions. This, however, has had me searching for roughly an hour and a half:

```
app.get('/api/:url(/^http:\/\/(.+?)\.(.+?)$/)', (req, res) => {
  // do stuff with req.params.url
});
```

Where every time I run the server locally and enter `localhost://8000/api/http://www.google.com`, the response is `Cannot GET /new/http://www.google.com`

I know the Regular Expression does what I want it to do, because :

```
/^http:\/\/(.+?)\.(.+?)$/.test('http://www.google.com');
```

... returns true.

I've also tried changing the route string to look like...

```
'/api/:url(^http:\/\/(.+?)\.(.+?)$)'

'/api/:url(http:\/\/(.+?)\.(.+?))'

'/api/:url/^http:\/\/(.+?)\.(.+?)$/'
```

And several other formats that look anything remotely like the examples given in Stack Overflow threads and blogs (the Express docs have absolutely no examples of a Regular Expression used outside of the first route param).  Perhaps there are some formatting constraints that I'm unaware of, or a limitation to RegExp support in Express? It'd be great if the docs said anything at all.

I appreciate any help I can get here.

Comment: Is it a typo or do you have `localhost` defined as a protocol? Shouldn't it be `http://localhost:8000/api/...` ?

Comment: That's just what I'm putting in the address bar of the browser, it really doesn't matter whether I include the protocol or not. Regardless that's not what I was asking about.

Comment: I was only curious, thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your regular expression is wrong, for what you're trying to achieve.

**TL;DR Use this one:**

```
app.get('/api/:url(https?:\/\/?[\da-z\.-]+\.[a-z\.]{2,6}\/?)', (req, res) => {
});
```

**Some explaining:**

Firstly, `path-to-regexp`, the module used by express does exactly what its name says: converts a path to a regular expression. As such, the `^` and `$` anchors are either illegal or can be interpreted differently when placed inside your `:url()` contents (*path-to-regexp already uses them*). Also, do not include the slashes used in JavaScript to identify RegExp objects, but only the expression content.

Here's how `express` sees your regular expressions:

```
path: '/api/:url(/^http://(.+?).(.+?)$/)'
regexp: /^\/api\/(?:(\/^http:\/\/(?:\.+?))\.(\.+?)$\/)\/?$/i

path: '/api/:url(^http://(.+?).(.+?)$)'
regexp: /^\/api\/(?:(^http:\/\/(?:\.+?))\.(\.+?)$)\/?$/i

path: '/api/:url(http://(.+?).(.+?))'
regexp: /^\/api\/(?:(http:\/\/(?:\.+?))\.(\.+?))\/?$/i

path: '/api/:url/^http://(.+?).(.+?)$/
regexp: /^\/api\/(?:([^\/]+?))\/^http:\/\/(?:\.+?)\.(\.+?)$\/?$/i
```

And, using a code snippet like this, you can see that none match:

```
const url = 'http://www.google.com';
for (let layer of app._router.stack) {
  if (layer.name === 'bound dispatch') {
    console.log(layer.regexp + ': matches', url, '=', layer.regexp.test(url));
  }
}
```

It's also advisable to avoid using capturing parentheses in an already named capture.

Example *(notice the extra parentheses around the scheme of the URI, and how they change the `req.params.url` value)*:

```
app.get('/api/:url((https?:\/\/)?[\da-z\.-]+\.[a-z\.]{2,6}\/?)', (req, res) => {})

> req.params: { '0': 'http://', url: 'http://' }
```

**Later edit:** Please note, this entire post is only about *string* routes that contain regular expression within, not routes defined with RegExp objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try double backslash

```
app.get('/api/:url(/^http:\\/\\/(.+?)\\.(.+?)$/)', ...
```

Comment: All that does is escape the backslash characters. Those backslash characters were put there to escape the forward-slash characters, to match a correct url.

Comment: humm. That works. Any clue why that one works while the other accurate Regex does not work in this context?

Comment: I should clarify: I want the one I wrote because it is more specific, and doesn't allow for things like extra slashes.

Comment: The result of  Express-code glance is [path-to-regexp](https://github.com/component/path-to-regexp) (express used this library to routing)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get it to work with named parameters, but you can pass a regular expression directly:

```
app.get(/^\/api\/http:\/\/(.+?)\.(.+?)$/, ...);
```

This will yield (as `req.params`):

```
{ '0': 'www', '1': 'google.com' }
```