# Javascript GET Request Parameters Showing up as Strings Instead of Numbers

Tags: javascript, node.js, restful-url, get-request

I'm writing a REST API and I have a route defined as follows:

`router.get("/objects/:id?/:val1?/:val2?", getObject);`

I'm sending the following get request from Postman:

```
http://localhost:8000/objects?val1=5&val2=6
```

I'm using express validator like this in getObject:

```
req.check("val1", "Invalid param: val1").notEmpty().isInt();
```

Even though I'm passing in numbers, when I it's only picking them up as strings. When I print to console using JSON.stringify(req.query), they also show as string instead of numbers. How would I go about fixing this? Would I have to cast the parameters as numbers? If I did, express validator wouldn't be as useful since it could only check for whether the parameter was passed in.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11260389/8225099) help?

Comment: Tried it, doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Everything passed in URL even as query string will be received as string at receiver's end. You will have to explicitly use:

```
Number(val1)
```

or

```
parseInt(val1)
```

to convert it to number.