# Why is Express.js routing not selecting correct route?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So I have the following route:

```
app.delete('/project/:id', crud.deleteProject);
app.delete('/project/resource/', crud.removeResourceFromProject);
```

When I run the ajax call with the url `http://mysite.no/project/resource/`:

```
delete: function(url,data) {
return $.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: "DELETE",
  dataType: 'json',
  data: data
});
```

Express runs the `crud.deleteProject` function.

If I comment out or move it below the other route, it works as expected.

Why is this?

Comment: In this case, the order of routes is very important. `:id` could be anything (eg. `135`, `foo`, `resource`). So, if your routes are declared the way you did, Express will find a match for `'/project/:id'` and will stop there. If you try to match `'/project/resource/'` first, it will not go on to check for other routes.

Comment: What's the point of using `:whatever` if express doesn't match it exactly? I thought the whole point of routing was to match specific url's.

Comment: `:whatever` will, indeed, match anything. It can be useful in many situations, for example, to get a search query, which could contain numbers, letters, etc. However, you can restrict it to only numbers if you want to. Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258442/express-routes-parameter-conditions

Comment: Sorry if I'm a bit slow here, but... `:id` is a parameter, whilst `/resource/` is a path. So Express doesn't distinguish these two?

Comment: It does not know whether `resource` is a path or a parameter, until it finds a route that matches. If the first route that matches says it's a parameter, then it'll treat is as one. If the first route that matches says it's a path, then it'll treat it as a path. As I said earlier, the order of your middlewares is very important. You should check for the most specific routes first, and then the most "permissive" ones

Comment: Right, thanks. One last Q. Is this Express specific? Or does this logic apply to routing methods in general?

Comment: I've not worked with many route handlers, so I can't say it _always_ applies, but this logic also applies when using PHP CodeIgniter. And also when using URL rewriting in a .htaccess or vhosts file. You declare specific routes first so they match first, and then, the ones that may contain different parameters.

Answer (score 0):

In Express, the order of your routing definitions is important. It will perform the first matching route. As Blex states, `'/:id'` is a wildcard value and is matching `'/resource'` instead of skipping past and following the correct route definition.

A solution is to switch the definitions to have `'/project/resource'` defined before `'/project/:id'`

<s>A solution is to add another path layer eg `'/project/res/resource'` instead of `'/project/resource'` as Express will not match this to `'/:id'`.</s>

Comment: The easiest solution is to move the definition of static routes to above and all the `wildcards` should be below them.