# Express routes regex - correct syntax

Tags: express

I looked at the following posts but they did not help with this. It's probably simple, alas...

[Express routes parameter conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258442/express-routes-parameter-conditions)

https://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/

I have the following regex - `/^\d+x\d+/i`. I want a number separated by an `x`, so a route would be `/100x100`,

The regex works on it's own, but not as a route. I tried various escapeings but I keep getting a 404 back. What would be the correct syntax? (I tried something like this already `router.get('/\/^\d+x\d+/i')`)

PS - As my plan is only to accept `digit x digit`, I'd be happy to hear about any flaws in this regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an interesting problem. This is one solution to achieve what you are looking for.

```
router.get('^/:dimensions([0-9]+[x][0-9]+)', function(req, res) {
  //to show you that it hits the route and what it catches
  res.send('Route match for dimensions: ' + req.params.dimensions);
});
```

Comment: Yeah, this works! Why is it not possible to use the regex I supplied? Is it a syntax thing? Or is it just wrong? (if so why?- trying to improve my regex :)