# Node js express route conflict issue

Tags: node.js, express

In my node js application, I have the following routes.

```
router.get('/:id', [auth], asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const post = await postService.getPostById(req.params.id);
  res.json(post);
}));

router.get('/all', [auth], asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const posts = await postService.getAllPosts(req.user.id);
  res.json(posts);
}));
```

Here, when I call the post/all route, it gets crashed. It says, ***Cast to ObjectId failed for value "all" at path "_id" for model "Post"Cast to ObjectId failed for value "all" at path "_id" for model "Post"***

But if I comment the first route, second one works perfectly. Why is this happening?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Express routes parameter conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258442/express-routes-parameter-conditions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because `/all` also matches `/:id`. What you need to do is move `/all` above `/:id`:

```
// Match this first
router.get('/all', [auth], asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const posts = await postService.getAllPosts(req.user.id);
  res.json(posts);
}));

// Then if not /all treat route as the variable `id`
router.get('/:id', [auth], asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const post = await postService.getPostById(req.params.id);
  res.json(post);
}));
```

Comment: After moving sequence you can not able to get data by id using your solution, you have yo change route path

Comment: @AnkurPatel Why would you not be able to? The code above works (tested) so you obviously can get data by id. Why do you think it may not work?

Comment: When you call using /:id it will redirect to /all route and getAllPosts() will excute

Comment: @AnkurPatel No it wont because `/123` does not match `/all` but will match `/:id`

Comment: @AnkurPatel unless your id is "all" but presumably there is no data with id of "all"

Answer (score 1):

because when you call /all route it will redirect to /:id route and try to convert all to objectId. so you need to change your route like this

```
router.get('/one/:id', [auth], asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const post = await postService.getPostById(req.params.id);
  res.json(post);
}));

router.get('/all', [auth], asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const posts = await postService.getAllPosts(req.user.id);
  res.json(posts);
}));`
```

Comment: It doesn't redirect. It just matches first. Express routes are middlewares. And just like middlewares they form an internal list of filters that get processed **in sequence**.